# How can I increase model Accuracy using contrastive learning SimCLR technique for Image Recognition?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, image-recognition

I have created a Convolutional Neural Network and I try to train it using SimCLR framework.
The problem with my training is that the Contrastive Loss is minimized in large values for training aproximately at 2.80 and this value affects a lot my predicted accuracy(14%).
I tried to use Linear or Logistic Regression as it was suggested in a paper with SimCLR but nothing changed. I used also both batch sizes 32 and 64 and for 200 epochs and more. But with increasing the batch size the training loss is increasing too. I think that is correct because in larger batch size more images are compared.
Can anyone help me find a solution?

I am presenting my model and my training code:

```
class ImgClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes = numClasses, in_channel =  in_channel):
        super(ImgClassifier, self).__init__()
        self.convnet = nn.Sequential(
            #1st Layer
            nn.Conv2d(3, 96, kernel_size=11, stride=4, padding=0),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(96),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size = 3, stride = 2),
            #2nd Layer
            nn.Conv2d(96, 256, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size = 3, stride = 2),
            #3rd Layer
            nn.Conv2d(256, 384, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(384),
            nn.ReLU(),
            #4th Layer
            nn.Conv2d(384, 384, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(384),
            nn.ReLU(),
            #5th Layer
            nn.Conv2d(384, 256, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size = 3, stride = 2),
            nn.Flatten(),
            #FC Layer
            nn.Linear(256 * 6 * 6, 4096),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(0.5),
            nn.Linear(4096, 4096),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(4096, numClasses)
        )
        self.projection_head = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(numClasses, 100),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Linear(100, 50),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Linear(50, numClasses)
        )
    def forward(self, x):
        output = self.convnet(x)
        output = self.projection_head(output)
        return output

classifier = ImgClassifier().to(device)
```

Training:

```
optimizer = optim.Adam(classifier.parameters(), lr = 1e-3)

train_loss_arr = []
val_loss_arr = []
best_loss = 50
for i in range(200):
    batch_train_loss = 0.0
    classifier.train()
    for img,_ in tqdm(train_loader):
        if (len(img)%batchSize) != 0:
            extra_img = loadImg(batchSize, len(img))
            img = torch.cat((img,extra_img[0]), dim =0) 
        img = img.to(device)

        img1 = contrast_trans(img)
        img2 = contrast_trans(img)
        pred1 = classifier(img1)
        pred2 = classifier(img2)
        
        train_loss = con_loss(pred1, pred2)
        
        batch_train_loss += round(train_loss.item(), 3)
        train_loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()

    train_loss_arr.append(batch_train_loss/ len(train_loader))
    if train_loss<best_loss:
        best_loss = train_loss
        with open(saveModelPath, 'wb') as f:
          save(classifier.state_dict(), f)
```

Thanks in advance!

I tried after the traininng to evaluate the model by using CrossEntropy loss function with predicted and actual labels but the results were disappointing. 10% with the projection_head and 14% without it. I want to mention that in the paper they suggest to remove the last fully connected layers for evaluating the model.